# textext render tags only after move mouse over input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-textext

I use plugin TextExt for autocomplete and tags

```
$('#keywords').textext({
        plugins : 'autocomplete tags',
        itemManager: CustomItemManager,
        tagsItems: [{value:'a', id:1}]
})
```

After page loaded tags does not rendered but only when i move mouse over the input field they will render. How can I force plugin render them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if someone is interested in solution.

Tags start render only after you move mouse over the text input element. I open html inspector to look on this element to see maybe tags have css rule `display: none;`, but I notice that my input element has event listener 'mousemove'(this event force rendering tags, plugin TextExt add it). So the solution is to trigger this event. In my case it was trigger this event after initializing 'textext'

```
$('#keywords').textext({
        plugins : 'autocomplete tags',
        itemManager: CustomItemManager,
        tagsItems: [{value:'a', id:1}]
})

$('#keywords').trigger('mousemove');
```